# Is there any way to merge the csv part files stored in ADLSGen2 using pyspark without converting the dataframe into python

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe which is loaded into ADLS after loading into ADLS it divides into part files. I want to merge all those part files using pyspark.

Comment: you can do `df.coalesce(1).write(...)` before writing/loading it into ADLS

Comment: Thanks.
 But, if i use repartition. How can we merge those part files?